# A simple .click() not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I am trying to click a div with Javascript. I can use Jquery. After I select the element using `QuerySelector` or `XPath` and use `.click()` on the element, it doesn't actually end up clicking the div and does nothing.

```
document.querySelector('.GriddyLayout > div:nth-child(1)').click()
```

The website I am trying it on is [here](https://www.ixl.com/math/grade-2/number-of-days-in-each-month). Running the code above in the Javascript console is not selecting the option for some reason. Does anyone know how to click this button (div) with JS so that it actually clicks? Will upvote all answers, and accept the one that works best/first.

Comment: Did you try `jquery` way? `$('.GriddyLayout > div:nth-child(1)').click();`

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which div are you trying to select?

Comment: `<div class="SelectableTile TEXT MULTIPLE_CHOICE natural" role="radio" aria-checked="false" style="width: 90px; height: 50px;" id="yui_3_14_0_1_1512889344567_1009"><div class="TileSkinBare CENTER MIDDLE"><div class="GeneticallyModified"><div id="yui_3_14_0_1_1512889344567_868">28</div></div></div></div>`

Comment: What about just: `document.querySelector('.GriddyLayout > div')`? Your selector seems redundant.

Comment: It didn't work. It is the right element, but it is not clicking. Check out the website, I think they might be trying to block the click with some JS.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 see my answer it is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger some events in specific sequence. In javascript, you could use:

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector('.GriddyLayout > div:nth-child(1)');

triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, "mousedown");
triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, "mouseup");
triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, "click");

function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
  var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
  node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: @A. Wolff How did you figure out that it requires all mousedown, up and then click?

Comment: @Miro By inspecting, using chrome's inspector, the fired events on element's click. This is btw a classic way to avoid some bot's click. Google is using this kind of trick too BUT very more complex

Answer (score 1):

You can  achieve  this by using plain JavaScript.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("GriddyLayout");
 for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked' +"  "+this.innerHTML);
});
}

function callClickEvents() {
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs[i].click();
}
}

setTimeout(function(){ callClickEvents() }, 100);

// click nth element i.e 3rd (2+1)
divs[2].click(); 
console.log("Now click all divs");
```

```html
<div class="GriddyLayout">hello 1</div>
<div class="GriddyLayout">hello 2</div>
<div class="GriddyLayout">hello 3</div>
<div class="GriddyLayout">hello 4</div>
                 .
<div class="GriddyLayout">hello n</div>
```

Comment: That is the wrong element. It doesn't refer to the button, it refers to the group of buttons

Comment: Maybe:
`document.getElementsByClassName('GriddyLayout')[0].firstElementChild.click();`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('GriddyLayout')[0]` is not the right element. I already tried the parents and children

Comment: What's weird that you don't have jquery but sizzle works. For example `$('.GriddyLayout > div:nth-child(1)').className += " selected";`  works. But there is not `click()` function.

Comment: @manikant check the website he linked. He's trying to "click" an answer without jQuery.

Comment: @Miro That changes the appearance, but not the actual option chosen. And I am ok with using Jquery

Answer (score 1):

[image]try this:`document.querySelector('.GriddyLayout > div:nth-child(1)').addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log('clicked')
})`

Comment: I tried on your site and it is working. Based on your code, it means that only the first option when clicked will log 'clicked'

Comment: Check the screenshot attached, It's strange that it is not working for you. When are you attaching the eventlistener?

Comment: Huh... That is weird. It doesn't work for me... It doesn't even say clicked

Comment: Make sure you are not attaching the eventlistener before the element is present in the DOM

Comment: But it would error if that happened because the element would not be visible. However, it did not error in my case, which means that it is a different problem

Answer (score 1):

Change selector to `.GriddyLayout > div.SelectableTile:nth-child(1)`. 
You aren't using jQuery.

With javascript

```
document.querySelector('.GriddyLayout > div.SelectableTile:nth-child(1)').addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('clicked');} );
```

With jQuery

```
jQuery('.GriddyLayout > div.SelectableTile:nth-child(1)').click(function() { console.log('clicked');});
```

Comment: This does not click the div, it justs adds an event listener for when the div is clicked.